# Regular Expression to match Digital Ocean Bucket Name Rule

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I tried to write the regular expression to validate the Digital Ocean Bucket Name which has rule like this

> Bucket names can consist only of lowercase letters, numbers, dots (.),
> and hyphens (-). Bucket names must begin and end with a letter or
> number.

I'm poor at regular expression. I could only solve the last rule "Bucket names must begin and end with a letter or number. With pattern `"^[a-z0-9].*[a-z0-9]$"`, but rule that consist of only lower case letter, number, dots, and hypnens

```
import re

# Start and end with letter or number
# pattern = "^[a-z0-9].*[a-z0-9]$"

# Start and end with letter or number, and consist only letter,
# number, dot, and hyphens
pattern = "^[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9\.\-]+[a-z0-9]$"


string_one = "hello world"
string_two = "hello ^ world 2"
string_three = "hello world *"
string_four = "Hello - World 9"
string_five = "hello - world 9"
string_six = "2hello.world 9"


if re.search(pattern, string_one):
    print "matched with string one: ",string_one

if re.search(pattern, string_two):
    print "matched with string two: ",string_two

if re.search(pattern, string_three):
    print "matched with string three: ",string_three

if re.search(pattern, string_four):
    print "matched with string four: ",string_four
```

But the above expressions, nothing is matched. However, it should match `string_one, string_five, and string_six` Could you please help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match string 1,5 and 6 and also allow a space in between and a single character `a-z0-9` to match:

```
^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9. -]*[a-z0-9]$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/65SZGc/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FPuxls)

Note that this matches at least 2 characters, and you don't have to escape the dot and the hyphen when it is at the end of the character class.

To also allow a single character:

```
^[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9. -]*[a-z0-9])?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uN8ZWb/1)